# How to click function for an auto built li list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

In my application, it parses data from an xml file and then show the data in a `<li>` list. 
So there is a `<ul>` list and a loop for the xml file to put some specific data in each `<li>` tag.
It successfully reads the xml file and creates the list, but the problem is that the list is kind of not active. For example, I made a `click` function so it gives `alert("done!");` when a `<li>` is clicked, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```js
var tracksArray = [];
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33538012/playlist.xml',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parse,
  error: function() {
    alert("Error: Something went wrong");
  }
});

function parse(document) {
  $(document).find("track").each(function() {
    tracksArray.push($(this).find('url').text());

    $(".panel1 ul").append(
      "<li id='row" + tracksArray.length + "'>" +
      "<p class='title'>" + $(this).find('title').text() + "</p>" +
      "</li>"
    );

  });
}


$(".panel1 ul li").on("click", function() {
  alert("done!");
})
```

```css
div.app {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
div.app > .blur {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
div.mainSection,
div.dashboard {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
div.mainSection {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
}
div.dashboard {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  bottom: 0;
}
div.mainSection > .panel1,
div.mainSection > .panel2,
div.mainSection > .panel3 {
  width: 100%;
  Height: 100%;
  Background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
div.mainSection > .panel3 > p {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
.grid-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.grid:after,
.grid:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.grid.open {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.grid.open:after {
  top: 10px;
}
.grid.open:before {
  top: -10px;
}
.grid.close {
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.grid.close:after,
.grid.close:before {
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.grid.close:before {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.grid.close:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">
  <div class="blur"></div>
  <div class="mainSection">
    <div class="panel1">
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel2" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="panel3" style="display: none;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the last part of the my js code is for giving alert if a `<li>` is clicked, but nothing happens.

Does anyone know why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you add the `onclick` listener directly to the `li` element, it will not work if the `li` is dinamicly appended/removed from the `ul` via AJAX callback. When you first attached the `onclick` to the `li`, which are not already appended to the `ul`, it will do nothing.

It can be done by attaching the `onclick` listener to the `ul` itself. then checks whether the target `li` clicked within the `ul`.

```
$('panel1 ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
   console.log('list clicked!');
});
```

That means every clicked elements within the `panel1 ul` will be delegated up to `ul`. And if it is `li`, the callback will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delegate:

```
$(document).on("click", "pane1 ul li", function(){ ... });
```

#### Sample

```js
function createLI() {
  var html = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5;) {
    html += "<li>" + ++i + "</li>";
  }
  $("#list").append(html);
}

function registerEvents() {
  $(document).on("click", "#content ul li", function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  })
}

registerEvents();
createLI();
```

```css
li {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because javascript run asyn.
When the data still waits for the ajax.

```
$(".panel1 ul li").on("click", function() {
alert("done!");
})
```

is already executed.
That's why it doesn't work!
You can simply put the on() function at the end of parse() function.
Here is my jsbin

https://jsbin.com/jicawe/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

A little change, move the click events into `function parse`. Since that ajax is asynchronous, when `$.ajax` is executed, it is executed in another thread and at the mean time `$(".panel1 ul li").on("click",...)` executes but finds the selector finds nothing. So moving click events into parse function ensures that the events is added after ajax is done.

```
function parse(document) {
  $(document).find("track").each(function() {
    tracksArray.push($(this).find('url').text());

    $(".panel1 ul").append(
      "<li id='row" + tracksArray.length + "'>" +
      "<p class='title'>" + $(this).find('title').text() + "</p>" +
      "</li>"
    );
  });
  $(".panel1 ul li").on("click", function() {
    alert("done!");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like following way.

Here apply concept of **[Event Propagation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**

So you can get click event like:

```
$('.panel1').on("click", "ul li", function(){
```

```js
var tracksArray = [];
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33538012/playlist.xml',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parse,
  error: function() {
    alert("Error: Something went wrong");
  }
});

function parse(document) {
  $(document).find("track").each(function() {
    tracksArray.push($(this).find('url').text());

    $(".panel1 ul").append(
      "<li id='row" + tracksArray.length + "'>" +
      "<p class='title'>" + $(this).find('title').text() + "</p>" +
      "</li>"
    );

  });
}

$('.panel1').on("click", "ul li", function(){
  alert( $( this ).children( "p" ).text());
})
```

```css
div.app {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
div.app > .blur {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
div.mainSection,
div.dashboard {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
div.mainSection {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
}
div.dashboard {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  bottom: 0;
}
div.mainSection > .panel1,
div.mainSection > .panel2,
div.mainSection > .panel3 {
  width: 100%;
  Height: 100%;
  Background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
div.mainSection > .panel3 > p {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
.grid-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.grid:after,
.grid:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.grid.open {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.grid.open:after {
  top: 10px;
}
.grid.open:before {
  top: -10px;
}
.grid.close {
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.grid.close:after,
.grid.close:before {
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.grid.close:before {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.grid.close:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">
  <div class="blur"></div>
  <div class="mainSection">
    <div class="panel1">
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel2" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="panel3" style="display: none;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Give a class to your `li`s like;

```
$(".panel1 ul").append(
  "<li class="lis" id='row" + tracksArray.length + "'>" +
  "<p class='title'>" + $(this).find('title').text() + "</p>" +
  "</li>"
);
```

And then try;

```
$(".lis").live("click", function(){
    alert("done!");
});
```